# ME23N Posting - Control could not be found by ID

Tags: vba, error-handling, purchase-order

I'm writing code to post/create PO's in ME23N by copying some data from an Excel looping.

The problem is that, when I try to run the script from the first Notebook[A] on the other [B], the second one gives the message: "The control could not be found by id".

Is there a way to use a variable for the "findById" code, so wherever I run it, it will copy data from Excel and paste it to a specific field?

"On error Go To 0" is not working because even with the error, I still need the information pasted to the field.

Below you can see my code.

```
Sub CTM()
    If Not IsObject(Applic) Then
       Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
       Set Applic = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    'session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
       Set Connection = Applic.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(session) Then
       Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
       WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
       WScript.ConnectObject Applic, "on"
    End If


    Dim num_linhas
    Dim lin_atual

    'Conta quantidade linhas
    num_linhas = Worksheets("Base").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox (num_linhas - 1)

    'Pega o numero da primeira linha cujo valor é diferente de zero
    For lin_atual = 2 To num_linhas

        'Abrir transação SAP
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "ME23N"
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[6]").press

        session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0030/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1105/ctxtMEPO_TOPLINE-SUPERFIELD").Text = "2000031572" ' FORNECEDOR
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0030/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1105/ctxtMEPO_TOPLINE-SUPERFIELD").SetFocus
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0030/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1105/ctxtMEPO_TOPLINE-SUPERFIELD").caretPosition = 10
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB1:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1102/tabsHEADER_DETAIL/tabpTABHDT3").Select
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB1:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1102/tabsHEADER_DETAIL/tabpTABHDT3/ssubTABSTRIPCONTROL2SUB:SAPLMEGUI:1230/subTEXTS:SAPLMMTE:0100/subEDITOR:SAPLMMTE:0101/cntlTEXT_EDITOR_0101/shellcont/shell").Text = Cells(lin_atual, 17) 'TEXTO
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB1:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1102/tabsHEADER_DETAIL/tabpTABHDT3/ssubTABSTRIPCONTROL2SUB:SAPLMEGUI:1230/subTEXTS:SAPLMMTE:0100/subEDITOR:SAPLMMTE:0101/cntlTEXT_EDITOR_0101/shellcont/shell").setSelectionIndexes 105, 105


        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11

        strTexto = session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text
        Cells(lin_atual, 21) = strTexto

ContinueForLoop:

    Next lin_atual

    MsgBox ("Documentos contabilizados")

End Sub
```